# Migrating an EAR application from AppEngine to Google Cloud SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ear, google-cloud-sdk

Since App Engine reached the end of life last August on the 30th, it's not possible anymore to deploy updates to the same application using the appengine (`appcfg`) command line.

I was using the appengine maven plugin which in turn was using appcfg to deploy my application.

I'm looking on how to migrate my application to Google Cloud SDK now but between the limitations I saw that Google Cloud SDK does not support EAR applications to be deployed.

Surprize surprize my applications does have an EAR structure.

Is there a workaround for this or should I completely change the structure of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change your application structure at all. It's only the deployment that it slightly altered.

Before, you used to create war artifacts and package them into a deployable ear.

Now you keep creating the same war artifacts but you must not package them into an ear. Instead, you deploy them all together using the gcloud command:

gcloud app deploy ./path_module1/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml ./path_module2/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

path_moduleX are paths to the exploded artifacts (not path to your source code, of course)

as explained here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files

Comment: Thanks for the response. But then I don't use a maven plugin to handle deployment?